# How to set a frequencies grid in Short Time Fourier Transform from SciPy?

Tags: python, scipy, fft

I perform a Short Time Fourier Transform as described [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.stft.html).

```
from scipy.signal import stft
f, t, Zxx = stft(data)
```

As far as I understand I get the following objects: (1) an 1D array containing values of frequencies, (2) an 1D array containing values of time, and (3) a 2D array containing intensities of a given frequency at given moment of time.

My question is about how to control / modify the grid of frequencies. Per default I got a grid of 129 frequencies. The first thing that I would like to do is to increase the number of frequencies (to have a more granular grid).

In addition to that, it would be nice to be able to specify what frequencies range should be used.

Comment: Keyword `fs` defaults to 1.0, but with it you can control the sampling frequency, but that only scales your frequency and time scales. What you are looking for is the keyword `nperseg=256`. If you play with this one, you will control the tradeoff between time segments and frequency segments. I am not quite sure if it is possible to specify a frequency range... :(

Answer (score 1):

As Uvar said, the range of observable frequencies is limited by the parameter `nperseg`. Given n samples, one can observe only `n/2 + 1` frequencies, namely the frequencies `fs*k/n` with `k = 0,1,2,...,n/2` where `fs` is the sampling frequency, and `n` is `nperseg`. Anything higher is lost due to [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing#Sampling_sinusoidal_functions). This is a mathematical limitation, nothing SciPy can do about it. To have a sufficiently granular list of frequencies, increase `nperseg`. The default value `nperseg = 256` gives (256/2) + 1 = 129 frequencies.

The discrete Fourier transform gives you all observable frequencies at once, it is not possible to choose a custom range. Of course, you can slice the output `f` to select the range of frequencies of interest.